# App crash when I'm trying to updating an app when returning from background in iOS using swift 3

Tags: swift3, ios10

I'm using this code in `viewdidload()`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("appWillEnterForeground:")), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: UIApplication.shared)
```

that call this function

```
func appWillEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification!) {
    // update label text here
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

but that app crash when it back to the foreground

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x160db800
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ appWillEnterForeground:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x160db800'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appWillEnterForeground:` tells the notification center to look for a method with that name, but which takes one parameter.  Your implementation of the method takes no parameters and therefore isn't seen as a correct match.

Try `Selector(("appWillEnterForeground")`.